# Numbering adjacent points/centroids in sequential order using QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, sorting

I am using QGIS 3.18.

I have, for example, this layer with points or centroids (with x, y coordinates)
[image]

I want to enumerate the points from right to left (for example) and top to bottom like this:

[image]

I tried sorting them using the `Sort and Number plugin` (using X and Y), I got close but not enough

I even tried to follow and modify the below

> [Automatically numbering points East-West & North-south on QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342293/automatically-numbering-points-east-west-north-south-on-qgis)

but still didn't get far
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this python script:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() #Click layer in layer tree
idfield = 'enum' #Change to match the name of your field

coords = [[f.geometry().asPoint().x(), f.geometry().asPoint().y(), f.id()] for f in layer.getFeatures()] #List x coordinate, y coordinate and id of each point
coords.sort(key=lambda k: (k[1],-k[0]), reverse=True) #Sort by y, x
order = [i[2] for i in coords] #Extract only the ids from the sorted list of lists

i = layer.fields().indexFromName(idfield)
attrMap = {id: {i:e} for e,id in enumerate(order,1)}
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

labeling the points with this expression:

```
array_find(
    array_reverse( 
        array_sort(array_agg($y))
                 ), $y)+1
```

+1 because arrays start from zero

[image]

Comment: I like this solution!

Comment: Very neat solution!
Both solutions are great. Too bad I cannot accept two answers. This solution is simple. However, BERA was fast to answer so I chose his solution! @pigreco